# How to set the select option can be type by numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set my select option received types in numbers. This is my code.

```html
 <select style="width:100px;" autofocus>
 <option disabled selected value></option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="3"></option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
```

If I type number 6, The select option should display the 6 without selecting in the option value. Please help me.

Comment: So where do you type 6? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: If I type 6 in keyboard, the 6 should display in select element. I don't know what or where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you are typing number 6 in a text box which have a id "inputarea".

Now you can get the typed value from that input box as follow;

```
var inputval = docuemnt.getElementById("inputarea").value;
```

Now that `inputval` can be set to the select box via;

```
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value = inputval;
```

**Note that the [0] means the first select box in the page, if you have multiple such box you have to put the index accordingly**

Now let's think you want something like there is no input box and you just want the select box be selected as 6 whenever you press button 6.

Then try this;

```
 window.onload = function(){
 {
    document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].focus();  // this will focus your select box
 }
```

Now try pressing the button 6.

Comment: Do you have any other solution without using input box? I have 40 select elements in my website and I think its too long to add input box in each elements.

Comment: check bottom part of my answer from "Now let's think you want something like there is no input box and you just want the select box be selected as 6 whenever you press button 6."

Comment: Thank you KOUSIK MANDAL, Ive got it now